# Stop image resize after animate once jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm using the window scroll function and I want to stop image resize after animate once in jQuery

```
    if(scroll >= 150){
        $('.abc').attr('src','one.jpg').animate({
            width: "5px",
            height: "5px"
        },
        function () { // fired the second time
            $(this).stop().animate({
                width: "50px",
                height: "50px",
            });
        });
}`
```

Answer (score 0):

```
This code will stop image resize after animate once Jquery. Please check    it and let me know.

$(window).scroll(function(){
        var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();



        if(scroll >= 150){           
            $('.abc img').attr('src','http://demo-stable-ofbiz.apache.org/images/products/GZ-1000/small.png').animate
            ({
              width: "5px",
              height: "5px" 
            },
            /* You can use this image resize stop function this way. */
              function(){                                                                                       
               $(this).stop();
            }                               
        } 
});
```

Comment: image resize 5 to 100 px then stop

Comment: I dont know how to make fiddle but i have tested this code in your fiddle.

Can you please tell me what you want ??

Comment: u can see my fiddle image resize animate 0 to 100 px once then stop ,now u understand

Comment: pls help developers i m stuck